# Printf - eliminante the junk

Tags: c

I am implementing a ring buffer. But when I use `printf` a lot of junk appears after what I want:

```
    char *dados1 = "XXXX";
    char *dados2 = "YYYY";
    char target_1[4];
    char target_2[1];
    RingBuffer *Buffer_em_Anel = RingBuffer_create(10);

    RingBuffer_write(Buffer_em_Anel, dados1, 4);
    RingBuffer_read(Buffer_em_Anel, target_1, 4);
    printf("actual buffer %s \n", Buffer_em_Anel->buffer);
    printf("Characters from read%s \n", target_1);//<---XXXX+lots_of_junk
```

In the debugging info, everything looks fine.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The buffer you are printing out only contains 4 characters of `X`.

When you use the `%s` specifier, printf will keep printing ALL characters until it encounters a NUL-terminator (`\0`).

You don't know where a `\0` will appear in memory, so printf will keep printing, potentially far beyond your 4 bytes, until it randomly encounters a `\0`.

To ONLY print 4 characters, I would try:

```
printf("actual buffer %.4s \n", Buffer_em_Anel->buffer);  // Note the 4 for width-specifier.
printf("Characters from read%.4s \n", target_1);
```

Comment: So, how can I make a proper printf?

Comment: That works :) @abelenky Is it possible that I will have problems with this "junk"? Imagine that I want to use `target_1` to write in a file, or to store in memory...or something else

Comment: You must write your program to track how much information to write out, and when to stop.   In C, "strings" always end with a `\0`.  But if you are not using null-terminated strings, you must track the size with an integer.

Comment: Ok I understand. In need to keep in memory the size of chunks that I want to manipulate. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

A C string is a **null terminated** char array. Assuming your `RingBuffer_write` function is a memcpy like function, you do not copy the `'\0'` that would signal the end of the string. So the junk after, in fact till the next null somewhere in memory.